# Should I use several maps or is there another way?

Tags: c++

thanks for watching this topic, I'm doing a Rogue-Like game to train myself to c++.
I was told that I should separate the data from the game and the logic, let me explain:

> I have a class named Monster

```
class Monster{
    public:
        Monster();
    private:
        string name;
        int damage;
        int healthPoints;
        MonsterType monsterType;
};
```

Those Monsters can have several type that I listed in an enum:
`enum MonsterType{NEKKER, ARACHAS, WOLF};`

Now I want that depending on the MonsterType I give to my Monster, he gets predefine stats :

Nekker should have 30Hp and 5 dmg, Arachas 25Hp and 7 dmg etc...

> So at first I was using something like that :

```
    switch (monsterType)
    {
    case NEKKER:
        damage = 5;
        break;
    etc...
```

But I was told that it's not a good use of switches and I should look about std::maps.

> So I get to that point :

In monster.h `static std::map<MonsterType, int> damageMap;`

In monster.cpp :

```
map<MonsterType, int> Monster::damageMap = {
    {NEKKER, 5},
    {ARACHAS, 7},
    {WOLF, 4}};
```

> I make it working like that :

```
void Monster::giveDamageFromMap(){
    if(damageMap.find(monsterType) != damageMap.end()){
        damage = (damageMap.find(monsterType)->second);
    }
```

But now I'm a bit lost, does this mean I should one map for each of my attribute ? Or can I have something better ? like a map that can have more than 2 columns. I have also the feeling that my `enum MonsterType` and the map are a bit redundant. If you have any advices or recommandations about how I should organize all this stuff it would be great ! Thank you :)

Comment: `std::map<MonsterType, Monster> mlut`, and make a copy of `mlut[type]` when you make a new monster: `Monster new_monster = mlut[type]`. Boom done.

Comment: It seems you just need a factory

Comment: I looked your suggestions about factory design pattern and I have managed to implement it, that's work well. However I don't know if I should have a class Factory that have methods to create all my classes (monsters / boss etc..) or if I should dispatch thoses methods in the class of the object I want to create ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple extension to your design would be to add a `Stats` struct:

```
struct Stats {
  int damage{};
  int healthPoints{};
};
```

and then your `Monster` becomes:

```
class Monster {
  public:
    Monster();
  private:
    string name;
    Stats stat;
    MonsterType monsterType;
};
```

This lets you use either a `switch` statement:

```
Stats get_predefine_stats(MonsterType mt) {
  switch(mt) {
    case MonsterType::Nekker : return {5, 30};
    case MonsterType::Arachas : return {7, 25};
    // ...
  }
}
```

or create a `map` object:

```
std::map<MonsterType, Stats> predefined_stats {
 {MonsterType::Nekker, {5, 30}},
 {MonsterType::Arachas, {7, 25}},
 // ...
};
```

Either way, you have the stats stored together and have a name for it, which makes using it much easier.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try something like, didn't think about it because I'm not familiar with structure :) , but that's true that it's easier as the data are stored together

Comment: There's actually nothing complicated about `struct` if you know what a `class` is. It's just a `class` with `public:` at the top :)

Answer (score -1):

I find maps very inconvenient so I use `Multimap`. Try this:
https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/04/10/maps-vectors-multimap

Comment: Eh? How is a `map` inconvenient for this use case in a way that `multimap` is not?

Comment: Since the hp and dmg is not unique it can be mapped to two type of monster.